# Как узнать дату установки приложения в смартфоне Asus Zenfon 5 A501CG?

Tags: java, android

OS: Android 4.4.2 KitKat

Как узнать дату установки приложения в смартфоне Asus Zenfon 5 A501CG?

Comment: С абсолютной точностью и 100% вероятностью сделать это невозможно. И, кажется из формулировки вашего вопроса, что он с программированием не связан.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а нельзя посмотреть на дату создания папки `/data/data/package`?

Comment: @pavel, в теории да. Но нужен рут и эта папка может не удалятся при удалении приложения. Т.е. может быть получится дату первой установки узнать, а не последней.

Answer (score 1):

При нажатии на кнопку выведет в лог - список всех установленных приложений с датой их первой установки на данный device.

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onBtnClick(View v) {
    List<PackageInfo> packageInfo = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(PackageInfo a:packageInfo){
        Log.d(a.packageName, "Дата первой установки : " + convertTime(a.firstInstallTime));
    }
}

String convertTime(long time){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd MMMM yyyy");
    return dateFormat.format(new Date(time));
   }
}
```

> Пример:
>
> > D/com.viber.voip: Дата первой установки : 13:57:33 05 октября 2015